# Help understanding this line of code from the Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

Yes  , I  have the concept of  localhost . it’s a webserver like IIS or Casine (for asp.net), where we can host our web application.
But understand my question or problem first .  my  question is very simple . in order to get the ‘AccessToken’
Will I have to deploy my application on webserver or I can use any  another realastic url for my application. Like : I have one deployed application URL named ‘www.diduce.com\index.aspx’  so
could I use this url for my  another application(ABC)  where  actual code has written  for getting the AccessToken from facebook .this application  (ABC) is compeletely different from application ‘Diduce’(which is deployed in webserver).
Sample code in ABC application:
fbSettings.PostAuthorizeUrl = “www.diduce.com\index.aspx” ;// this is another application(Diduce)  URl which hosted in webserver.

I guess now understood  my question .

Answer (score 2):

I think `localhost:16443` assumes you're testing this on a local webserver, like Apache or Lighttpd.

You'd replace that with the address of the server which is hosting your page, like `http://example.com/`.

Comment: I am using this code for C# Window Application, I am not using any web application. can any of them give me the right solution. I just want to upload pictures through c# window application into my Facebook account.

Comment: You'd have to register your application as a FB application. FB will give you some sort of API key, which you will have to send FB in order to communicate with the user. Your API key will get shoved into a special URL which you will ask the user to open (to authorize your application with the person's account). THEN, you can do what you want...

Comment: Yes, you are  right I am able to generate the API key but my question is still where I can find the that URL . may be I am not able to understand what you are saying ,can you give me any sample project?    Please help me. no body able to understand my point.

Comment: I followed your instruction but I got the following error:            An error occurred with diduce. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.                                      if you want then I can give u the code.I just make small application in asp.net . http://localhost:7135/abc/fbregcallback.aspx

Comment: `localhost` is on *your* computer. It's not an actual website address. You'll have to host your code somewhere or obtain a static IP and host it from your own computer. Facebook needs an actual URL of a website, so `localhost` won't work. Google **"host a website from home"**.

Comment: Why its need ,I can't do it  without any url as I want window application there is no any concept of any url.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of localhost:16443 is as follows.
the `localhost` part is the beginning part of a URL such as `http://www.google.com` the `16443` part is the port that the server is listening on.

Comment: Why its need ,I can't do it  without any url as I want window application there is no any concept of any url.

Comment: Even, I tried  with following url ,which hosted . http://www.diduce.com/index.aspx ,but still I am getting same error.

Comment: are you deploying this to IIS or some other web server?

Comment: Yes, I deployed the one appliaction www.diduce.com\index.aspx  and i used this url to another application where I written actual code for accessing the AccessToken. now Please tell me where I am missing anything in order  to get the AccessToken.

Comment: if you don't understand the concept of localhost there is zero chance I am going to write out a tome of text to explain to you how to do your job.